# VHDL Clock Divider: Counter - Duty Cycle

Tags: counter, vhdl, clock, frequency

I am new to VHDL. I was given this code on how to generate a clock signal of 1Hz (50 % duty cycle) from input clock signal of 24 MHz. I have some questions for more clarification.

1. How is the counter limit chosen? in the below case, 12000000. What
   would this limit be if I want generate an 8Hz clock signal.
2. How should the code be adjusted if I wanted to change the duty cycle
   to 80% ?

   ```
   library IEEE;
   use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
   use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
   use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
   entity clock is
      port ( CLKin: in std_logic;
             reset: in std_logic;
             CLKout: out std_logic);
   end clock;
   architecture arch of clock is

     signal counter: integer:=0;
     signal temp : std_logic := '1';
   begin
   process(CLKin,counter,reset)
   begin
      if(reset='0') then counter<=0; temp<='1';
       elsif(CLKin'event and CLKin='1') then counter <=counter+1;
        if (counter = 12000000) then temp <= NOT temp; counter<=0;
        end if;
       end if;
      CLKout <= temp;
   end process;
   end arch;
   ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to divide a clock of 24MHz, being 24000000 Hz, to 1 Hz.
So you create a counter that will count up every rising edge of the CLKin (24 MHz).
After 24000000/2=12000000 counts, you are in the middle.  That's where you change the level value of the output signal (`temp <= not temp`). Because you spec say it has to be a duty cycle of 50%.  When doing so, you also starts counting again from the start.

For 8MHz, you have have a counter to (24000000/8)/2 = 1500000.

And just a small remark: it's better to use the `ieee.numeric_std` library i.s.o the `ieee_logic_arith` and the `ieee.std_logic_unsigned`

Note: the code is first assigning to a signal`temp`.  And then the signal `temp` to output `clkout`.  The reason behind this is that in VHDL it is not allowed to read from an output port (`clkout`).  And you should read from it when doing the `output <= not output;`.  From a signal, reading is allowed.

And one more note: in the sensitivity list of the process, there is no need to have the `counter` signal there.

```
process(CLKin, reset) -- no counter needed
```

And, another thing...  Counting 12000000 cycles is: 0 -> (12000000-1) = 11999999